# Cannot push a specific object property into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to push all the properties of a student object into an array which holds student objects. All my properties save one, which is a property containing an array of strings get pushed into the students array and I'm not sure why. When I try and print the (first)element containing the array to the console it states that it is undefined. Here is the code I have so far:

```
var person = { firstname: "", lastname: "", email: "" };
function Student(){};
Student.prototype = person;
Student.prototype.sid = "";
Student.prototype.courses = [];
var students = [];



var answer = null;

function getstudents(answer, students){
    var teststudent = new Student;
    for(var i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
        if (i < 4) {
            teststudent[i] = answer[i];

        }
        if(i > 3) {
            teststudent.courses[i] = answer[i];
            console.log(teststudent.courses[i]); //element is defined
        }

    }
    students.push(teststudent);
    console.log("printing ", students[0][4]); //states that the element is undefined
}

function getanswer(string) {
    answer = string;
    return answer;
}



do {
    getanswer(prompt("Please enter your first name, last name, student ID, email and courses (seperated by ',')"));
    if(answer !== ""){
        var array = answer.split(',');
        answer = array;
        getstudents(answer, students);
    } else {
        answer = null;
    }


} while(answer !== null );
```

Comment: You are trying to set values of `teststudent[0]` to `teststudent[3]` when you should be setting the values of `teststudent['firstname']` etc.

Comment: Please 1) tell what exactly you want to see after "printing", 2) show how you call function `getstudent`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean:

```
teststudent.courses[i-4] = answer[i];
```